# Info from database and transform in Json to show in bootgrid in the view

Tags: json, database, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to show data that I get from a database in a bootgrid, but I have error in the method that transform the data in a json. Show me error like "cannot convert from 'system.collections.generic.list to currency ", "cannot convert from int to currency" and "cannot convert from String[] to currency"

```
enter code here  public ActionResult listCurrencyJson()
    {
        string strJson = "";
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            var keyValues = new Dictionary<string, currency>
                       {
                           { "rows", context.currency.ToList()},
                           { "rowCount", context.currency.Count()}
                           {"current", Request.Params.GetValues("current")}
                       };

            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            strJson = js.Serialize(keyValues);
            return Json(strJson, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json(strJson, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: what is this currency? is a List<T> ?

Comment: I resolve the problem of the Dictionary with Dictionary<string, object> but when I do this 2 lines JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            strJson = js.Serialize(keyValues); the Value I get type Datetime return a diferent format like /Date(1422943200000)/